# Cmake isnt parsing correctly in QTCreator

Tags: qt, cmake

I cloned a Repo and am trying to build it in QTcreator but I run into issues[image: Issue]

I tried to open the **CMakeLists.txt** but to no avail the build doesn't work. I tried making a new project and that works fine. The issue is with opening a existing project and building it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want to have a code and the build log to be in the question post **as text**, not linked as an *image*. Please, [edit] the question post and correct this issue. Note, that currently provided configuration log misses an **error message**. Phrase "Configuring incomplete, errors occurred" just means that *some* error has been occurred, without specifying that error. More detailed error description should be somewhere before in the log.

Answer (score 0):

CMake fails on configuration step. I take it, QtCreator parses files that are generated by CMake and since it fails, there are no files to parse. Check CMake output and figure out what's wrong with it (probably, it can't find some headers or libraries).